# Android NDK with C++ Graphics Engine

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk, ogre3d

I would like to use the C++ Graphics Engine (Ogre3D) I am familiar with to write some games for Droid (I just cannot get used to Java) and there are plenty of write ups on how to build the applications. However, I have been unable to get an answered at all concerning input.

Does the NDK provide the Droid functionality for input, such as Touch/Slide/Swipe/Zoom/etc? I have only used OIS with Ogre3D in the past, and am quite confused as to what the case is with Input handling for the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What NDK provides is only the lowest part of frame buffer processing in C with available casting from java objects using jini. IMO you should wait for a ogre port to android (which can never happen) or die trying to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LibGDX for a OpenGL ES2.x accelerated back-end that can import Ogre3D mesh. Or pick one of the other more mature 3D engines, Ogre3D Android support is just not there, and the OGLES2.x port is by a MAC developer, so it's iOS inclined. Don't expect it to change much soon... look for alternatives.